# bulk_save_objects() update issue

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy, bulk

I'm going to insert/update objects using `bulk_save_objects()`.

The insert is OK, but when an update is going to be done, it tries to update the primary key which obviously has not been changed.

Entity:

```
class MyObject(object):

    def __init__(self, id: int, f1: int, f2: int):
        self.id = id
        self.f1 = f1
        self.f2 = f2
```

Mapping:

```
my_table = Table('MyObject', metadata,
                 Column('Id', Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True),
                 Column('F1', Integer),
                 Column('F2', Integer))

mapper(MyObject, my_table,
       properties={
           'id': my_table.c.Id,
           'f1': my_table.c.F1,
           'f2': my_table.c.F2
       })
```

Repo:

```
def save_my_objects(self, my_objects: List[MyObject]):
    self.session.bulk_save_objects(my_objects, return_defaults=True)
    self.session.commit()
```

Logic:

```
my_objects = list()
my_objects.append(MyObject(None, 1, 2))

Repo.save_my_objects(my_objects)

my_objects[0].f1 = 15
Repo.save_my_objects(my_objects)  # Cannot update identity column 'Id'
```

Comment: @IljaEverilä I did it

Comment: As said in the docs, it should ignore primary keys when forming the SET clause of an UPDATE statement. It actually does that, if you use Declarative model classes (as compared to classical mapping such as yours). Maybe you've found an issue.

Comment: It would seem to be related to mapping the columns to attributes with different name. If you skip that, it works.